# How to post in Facebook without using the Android Facebook SDK from Android devices

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an app which will allow me to post on Facebook.

But I want a native application to post without any external SDK's. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Facebook Authentication docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

If you need to authenticate your mobile app against Facebook, then follow the `Client-side Flow` (further down the page). If you also have a server, then use `Server-side flow`.

For server-side implementation see LeanEngine classes FacebookAuth and FacebookLoginServlet: https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Server/tree/master/lean-server-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/server/auth

On the client side you can use it via a WebView: https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Android/blob/master/lean-android-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/LoginDialog.java